# When is using JS frameworks overkill for dev an application

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, backbone.js, ember.js

So Im currently dev a JS library which currently does a series of operations and uses other frameworks to produce a series of charts... My question is should I be using a framework like backbone.js or ember.js to leverage and make my application better?
I am wondering if I should be leveraging some sort of framework to write my application out? I  have been treating this as a plugin/class. Where should i draw the line?

**Application Flow:**

1. Get dataset of all the graphs it needs to build with titles etc... this can be 100+ graphs
   Build HTML markup based on dataset.
2. On DOM Ready call my Graph lib for each graph div that was added in the markup... it will do a series of operations to build the graph like an AJAX call to get the data / prep the data / load the graph via 3rd party framework.
3. User can interact with these graphs by clicking them and setting focus to a main content.
4. windows where they have options and more detailed info on the graph.

**Currently I'm writing like this.**

```
var App = App || {};    
App.Graph = function(options){
       var _default = {version:null};
       var _options = extend(options,_default);
       var __int = function(){
            // do work....
       };
       var __getData = function(){
            // do work...
       };
       var __genChart = function(){ 
           // do work...
       };
       var __load = function(loadBig,callback){
           // do work....
       };
       this.load = function(big,callback){
           // do work....
       };
       __init();
    };
```

**Vs. something like... I know i'm probably not doing this right.**

```
App.Graph = Ember.Object.extend({
  init: function(thing){
      // do work...
  },
  load: function(thing) {
     // do work...
     var __int = function(){
        // do work....
     };
     var __getData = function(){
        // do work...
     };
     var __genChart = function(){ 
       // do work...
     };
     var __load = function(loadBig,callback){
       // do work....
     };
     return __load(loadBig,callback);
  }
});
```

**Vs. maybe a combination so i can reuse the graph framework...**

```
  var Graph = function(options){
       var _default = {version:null};
       var _options = extend(options,_default);
       var __int = function(){
            // do work....
       };
       var __getData = function(){
            // do work...
       };
       var __genChart = function(){ 
           // do work...
       };
       var __load = function(loadBig,callback){
           // do work....
       };
       this.load = function(big,callback){
           // do work....
           return __genChart();
       };
       __init();
    }; 
   var App = Ember.Object.extend({
      graph: null,
      init: function(thing){
          // do work...
          this.graph = new Graph();
      },
      load: function(thing) {
         // do work...
         return this.graph.load(big,callback);
      }
    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a pretty broad topic, especially when the only thing we know about your app is that it produces charts. Is there a particular reason why you specifically single out backbone and ember? I notice you've also used the jquery tag...

Comment: @nnnnnn So the app will produce interactive graphs lots of them when the user selects one it will load another graph in a main page and the user can act on that graph... so there is allot more going on with the Graph lib.  I tried not to use a Jquery ref there shouldn't be..

Comment: After using many JS frameworks like YUI3, Backbone, CanJS etc, what I can say is, frameworks bring in well documented structure in to your application. Assume you are working in a team, every body knows what to expect when they have to implement a functionality. Also it takes out common boilerplate code. ex:Backbone has in events hash, it takes out the code that you write to add listeners, and implement a standard of using delegates for same, and provide clean API to clear those listeners and references. So frameworks do help up to some level, you skip spending a lot time writing initial code.